# Troi plugin function not working in FileMaker WebDirect

Tags: web, plugins, scripting, filemaker

For purposes of being able to select from multiple file from the computer or network, I am using the following script command which works great in native FileMaker 14:

Set Variable [$dosFN; value: TrFile_SelectFileDialog( " -AllowMultipleFiles" ; "Please select one or more files" ;)]

In testing to make sure this works, I am doing a custom dialog to display the value of $dosFN and an example that successfully comes back would show:

From drive as:
C:\Files\img1.jpg
C:\Files\img2.jpg

or from network as:
\\ACI-2008-01\Files\img1.jpg
\\ACI-2008-01\FIles\img2.jpg

What is not work is when I attempt the same thing in a webdirect environment which is only showing the following when I perform the same script without even a file selection dialog box:

$$-4222

So how can I possibly make this work as desired in a webdirect environment?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. This call is supposed to display the select file dialog. The plug-in does this by calling a function from one of the system libraries. In Web Direct you work with the database via a browser. Behind the scenes FileMaker silently converts the layouts and scripts into something that can run in the browser (lots of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). But it cannot convert all and this call is one of things it cannot convert. As a result the plug-in only runs on the FileMaker server in a completely different environment and has no way to make a system call on another computer.

You may have better luck with FileMaker's own Insert File script step. It seems to be compatible with Web Direct. It cannot select multiple files though. (Also, other plug-in functions may still work in Web Direct but keep in mind that they actually run on the server, not the computer that runs the browser.)

Comment: I was wrong in my answer, so +1 to Mikhail. Although, troi plugin is webdirect compatible, TrFile_SelectFileDialog is not. The only other alternative would be to inject some PHP or other web technology.

Comment: That's a shame with Troi, am going to start looking at 360Works SuperContainer next over at http://www.360works.com/supercontainer/

Comment: You are right, this is probably the better choice for the web. They definitely have file upload, not sure if it can take multiple files though. There is one way to find out - get a trial.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Troi file seems to be webdirect compatible, but it has to be installed on the FileMaker server as a server-side plugin. In any case check their documentation first, as it is usually quite detailed and if it does not help, you might get in touch with their support.

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand it, the plug-in is running server side and has no way to display an interface on the client side (web browser). I do not believe there is a way to do what you are trying to do with Troi File, but you may just need to contact Troi.